# dotnet pack reads an empty VCTargetsPath

Tags: visual-studio, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, dotnet-tool

I am building a Nuget package with Azure Pipelines.

The pipeline is run by a self hosted agent.
It works perfectly for pure .NET and .NET framework projects, but I get an error with a (VS2022) solution that contains a C++ project.

The build step completes without errors, but dotnet pack gives the error:

> C:\agents\A1_work\72\s\CPPProject\CPPProject.vcxproj(31,3): error
> MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not
> found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on
> disk.

This is the line in CPPProject that gives the error:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
```

This is the YAML code for dotnet pack:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet pack'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        projects: '$(projectFolder)/${{ parameters.projectName }}.csproj'
        custom: pack
        arguments: '--no-build --configuration Release -p:PackageId=$(packageName) -p:Authors="MyCompany" --output "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Package"'
```

Why do I get this error in dotnet pack when the solution builds without problems? How do I fix it?

If I change the VCTargetsPath environment variable on my build server to point to the VS2022 installation folder, it will affect the other projects that do not use VS2022.

I could maybe use a .props file to override the value, but it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I added this parameter `-p:VCTargetsPath` to dotnet pack:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet pack'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        projects: '$(projectFolder)/${{ parameters.projectName }}.csproj'
        custom: pack
        arguments: '--no-build --configuration Release -p:PackageId=$(packageName) -p:Authors="MyCompany" -p:VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\\" --output "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Package"'
```

This made the error go away.